# How do you add an Arrayformula in column header in google sheet and adding predefined text to populate in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas

This is my formula
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT("https://www.google.com/search?q=",J2:J))
Problem is I do not want this one below to appear in row 1 of J1
https://www.google.com/search?q=
I want this --> https://www.google.com/search?q= <---- to start in J2
I do not know how to do it. Please help or advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Some_title"; CONCAT("https://www.google.com/search?q=",J2:J)})
```

or if you want J1 to be empty

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({""; CONCAT("https://www.google.com/search?q=",J2:J)})
```

Comment: Thank you and my array formula worked.

Comment: Sorry, wrong grammar. Thank you and your array formula worked! Thank you JPV for the help and assistance.

Comment: If I could ask an advise on how to array formula in the column header the following formula           =image((QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 E2, 
 "//div/img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'http' limit 1", 0)),4,80,80)

Comment: I tried this by adding the formula above but I can't figure it out. =ARRAYFORMULA({"5TH";=image((QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 I2:I, 
 "//div/img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'http' limit 1", 0)),4,80,80) })

Comment: still not working    =ARRAYFORMULA({"";image((QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCAT(
 I2:I, 
 "//div/img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'http' limit 1", 0)),4,80,80) }))

Comment: I was thinking this was close, but not working     =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I),{""},IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCAT(
 I2:I), 
 "//div/img/@src"), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'http' limit 1", 0)),4,80,80) })

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Please [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Maybe start a new thread with your new questions and if possible share some sample data as it will greatly improve your chances of getting a solution fast.